# Convert POJO Array to JSONObject

Tags: json, gson

My print statement returns the following String where 'movies' is ArrayList of class 'Movies'.

```
System.out.print(new Gson().toJson(movies))
```

O/P

```
[{"movie_name":"Interstellar11","movie_rating":0.0,"votes_numb":0,"theatreNameList":[],"showTimingList":[]},{"movie_name":"Titanic","movie_rating":0.0,"votes_numb":0,"theatreNameList":[],"showTimingList":[]},{"movie_name":"Titanic66","movie_rating":0.0,"votes_numb":0,"theatreNameList":[],"showTimingList":[]},{"movie_name":"Avatar","movie_rating":0.0,"votes_numb":0,"theatreNameList":[],"showTimingList":[]}]
```

I want to convert the above String to JSON. When I pass the above String to:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(movies))
```

it shows me error as `org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1`

How do I convert the above String to JSONObject?

Comment: It's not a JSONObject but an JSONArray, thats why you get this error

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to hold the objects.

```
public class Movie_Details{
   private String movie_name;
   private String movie_rating;
   private String votes_numb;
   private ArrayList theatreNameList;
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Movie_Details[] movie_details = gson.fromJson(input, Movie_Details[].class); //input is your String
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(movie_details));// Print array.
```

**Reference Article:** http://blog.patrickbaumann.com/2011/11/gson-array-deserialization/